xlookup with mutiple criteria
I'm creating a fantasy football spreadsheet and I'm looking to use double xlookup to return data based on two criteria.
I lookup the values in "draft day" column B in "schedules" column A and then lookup the values in "schedules" row 2 in "fantasy points allowed 2023" column A and finally return the values in "fantasy points allowed 2023" column C.
Value is returned on sheet 1 column c "average porj points"
I tried
=XLOOKUP(B3,'schedules'A2:A,XLOOKUP('schedules'B2,'fantasy points allowed 2023'!A4:A35,'fantasy points allowed 2023'!C4:C35)

It returned an error

Array arguments to XLOOKUP are of different size

I'm looking to return a value for "Draft day d3" so I lookup the value in "b3 draft day" in "schedules" which would be "A5 schedules" and then look up the first corresponding team name "B5" (NJY) in "fantasy points allowed 2023" which should return 15.28. The end result should be the average of the corresponding numbers from every team that Josh Allen plays (NYJ    LV  WSH MIA JAX NYG NE  TB  CIN DEN NYJ)




It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12iUPKVFaL9wveZj0NtIyrxieuQYIK8U13kfixU7tMF8/edit?gid=771491280#gid=771491280.

Hope this helps, I edited the post to reflect the actual spreadsheet names. Also, the errors in "Draft Day" don't really matter because I those columns are not necessary to the issue. The formula should go in column C on the "draft day" sheet. Please let me know what else I can do to help.

1) Would you please ensure that the data is entirely consistent with the question. e.g.  "Schedules"!C5 = LV, but no "LV" in Col A of "Fantasy Poinst Allowed 2023", ditto "NE" (in the schedule twice but not "Fantasy points") and "BYE" (not "Fantasy Points"). Also Draft Day per question = 22 lines but spreadsheet = 31 lines. 2) The end result should be the average of the corresponding numbers from every team that Josh Allen plays (NYJ LV WSH MIA JAX NYG NE TB CIN DEN NYJ) Would you please edit the question to include the expected results for each Team in "Draft Day".

Try this (not guaranteed but poss correct IF you fix LV, NE and BYE): Insert in Cell C3 of Draft Day. =average(map(chooserows(Schedules!$B$1:$S$33,match(B3:B33,Schedules!$A$1:$A$33,0)),lambda(c,vlookup(c,'Fantasy Poinst Allowed 2023'!$A$4:$C$35,3,0))))

Manually calculate & showcase your ideal expected output for a scenario or two so as for us to tally the numbers when we do the formula...

@Tedinoz - That worked! I've never used the "map" function before, I'll have to look into that more. Thank you so Much!!

That worked Well, that's good news but is the answer correct?? Two things: 1) please update your sample data to include some expected outcomes (manually calculated - as rockinfreakshow has mentioned).  2) I had expected that the formula would automatically populate the rows in the column, at least down to line 33. I'll look at it but I'm pretty rusty on Map/Lambda; I'm thinking that @rockinfreakshow might be able get it to expand down the column

OK, try this in cell C3 of Draft Day: =IFERROR(BYROW(arrayformula(vlookup(vlookup(B3:B33,Schedules!$A$2:$S$33,{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19},false),'Fantasy Poinst Allowed 2023'!$A$4:$C$35,3,0)), LAMBDA(x, AVERAGE(x))),99)
